# Caching external resources with sw-precache

Tags: progressive-web-apps, sw-precache

I'm trying to get `sw-precache` to pre-cache external CDN resources, but the generated service-worker.js doesn't contain the CDN url's in the `precacheConfig` array.

This is what I have in my `gulpfile`:

```
staticFileGlobs: [
    'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css',
     'client/assets/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif,svg,eot,ttf,woff,ico}'
]
```

The files inside my local `client/assets` folder are added to the `precacheConfig` array, but the external font-awesome css isn't. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sw-precache` can only precache and keep up to date local assets, like those that match the `client/assets/**/*...` pattern you're using. It's not meant to work with remote assets that are accessed via CDN.

You have a couple of approaches:

1. Use `npm` (or the package manager or your choice) to download a local copy of the resource (i.e. [font-awesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome)) and then deploy that third party resource alongside your first-party assets. If the third-party code is picked up by a pattern you pass to `staticFileGlobs` then it can be precached and versioned just like anything else local.
2. Use runtime caching to handle the resource on the CDN. Since the URL for your specific asset includes a `4.0.3` versioning string, it's safe to assume that the underlying contents will never change, and a `cacheFirst` strategy is probably safe.

You can modify your `sw-precache` configuration to look like the following:

```
{
  staticFileGlobs: [
    'client/assets/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif,svg,eot,ttf,woff,ico}'
  ],
  runtimeCaching: [{
    urlPattern: /^https:\/\/netdna\.bootstrapcdn\.com\//,
    handler: 'cacheFirst'
  }],
  // ...any other config options...
}
```

That configuration is broad enough to pick up anything served off that CDN, cache it, and then serve it cache-first once in subsequent visits.

**Please note that your example used an `http:` protocol for your CDN's URL, and you'll need to use `https:` to obtain a response that plays nicely with service worker caching.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I already have a runtimeCaching urlPattern like you suggested, my problem occurred when a user would access my pwa for the first time (pre-caching everything in staticFileGlobs) and then accessed it offline on the second visit. The font-awesome was never downloaded by the service-worker, because the only time it was downloaded by the browser was when the service-worker was still installing (meaning the runtimeCaching wasn't yet in use).

Comment: I had already considered using a local copy but was wondering if there was a way to avoid it. I'm gonna use that approach, like you suggested.
Thanks for your note also, I wasn't aware of that :)

Comment: @zeodamaster hack around that by loading an hidden iframe containing your page after the service worker installs

Comment: Hi,this is more useful for me.Can I exclude my subsite url for precaching